# UWP compatible package of a .NET library

Tags: .net, uwp, nuget

I'm developing a .NET library which targets .NET Framework and .NET Standard, and contains Win API calls. Win API calls are prohibited by UWP. The library provided as a NuGet package.

My question is how properly support UWP in the library? Should I create separate package (with .Uwp suffix for example) where all Win API calls are replaced by UWP API calls? Or maybe it's possible to identify platform at runtime and thus have all in one package? Should I target `uap` or `uap10.0` in csproj metadata?

Maybe someone has experience with similar task?

**Edit 1:**

Problem is due to [the issue](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/issues/108) from the user of the library:

> Validating UWP packages using DryWetMidi to deploy applications to the
> store results in
>
> FAILED Supported APIs Error Found: The supported APIs test detected
> the following errors: API midiInAddBuffer in winmm.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API
> midiInClose in winmm.dll is not supported for this application type.
> Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiInGetDevCapsA in winmm.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API
> midiInGetErrorTextA in winmm.dll is not supported for this application
> type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiInGetNumDevs in winmm.dll is
> not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API.
> API midiInOpen in winmm.dll is not supported for this application
> type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiInPrepareHeader in winmm.dll
> is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this
> API. API midiInReset in winmm.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiInStart in
> winmm.dll is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll
> calls this API. API midiInStop in winmm.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API
> midiInUnprepareHeader in winmm.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiOutClose in
> winmm.dll is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll
> calls this API. API midiOutGetDevCapsA in winmm.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API
> midiOutGetErrorTextA in winmm.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiOutGetNumDevs in
> winmm.dll is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll
> calls this API. API midiOutGetVolume in winmm.dll is not supported for
> this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiOutLongMsg
> in winmm.dll is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll
> calls this API. API midiOutOpen in winmm.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiOutPrepareHeader
> in winmm.dll is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll
> calls this API. API midiOutSetVolume in winmm.dll is not supported for
> this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API midiOutShortMsg
> in winmm.dll is not supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll
> calls this API. API midiOutUnprepareHeader in winmm.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API. API
> timeKillEvent in winmm.dll is not supported for this application type.
> Coimbra.dll calls this API. API timeSetEvent in winmm.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Coimbra.dll calls this API.
> Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK
> for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification
> requirements. How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the
> API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps.
> Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without
> .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these
> environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a
> release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See
> the link below for more information: Alternatives to Windows APIs in
> Microsoft Store apps. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=244022

Comment: UWP could reference a .NET Standard 2.0 library. If the win API is supported by .NET Standard 2.0, then it should be able to use in UWP.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have single codebase that can be built to a package that can be used in UWP app without problems. Is it possible? If yes, I'd like to know how to do this :)

Comment: As I mentioned, if you want to create a library that could be used in UWP apps, you could create a .NET Standard 2.0 library, APIs that supported by .NET Standard 2.0 is able to use in UWP apps.

Comment: No. As I said right now I have Win API calls in my library which is prohibited by UWP. I need to use UWP API. But it's impossible to use UWP API in .NET Standard library. So I have the question how to have single codebase to generate both .NEt Standard and UWP packages.

Comment: UWP could use win APIs. UWP could reference a .NET Standard 2.0 library and call 
.net APIs that come from .NET Standard 2.0. If you want to create a single codebase, then you should only use APIs in .NET Standard 2.0. If you have requirements using other APIs, then you have to build a new UWP library for the UWP project.

Comment: You're right. I've added info about the issue on the GitHub. Thanks, so as I thought I need to build new library that uses UWP API...